# Image style not generated for specific content type in amazon s3

Tags: 7, media

I have store images/files in amazon s3 using **s3fs module** when I upload images/files it stores in default public files on s3 server like **s3fs-public** folder . But I want to store images/files on specific **image styles** which I have created in back-end for specific content type . But images/files not store in specific **image styles**. So, can anyone tell me how to solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Style - instances of images are not generated at upload. They are generated "on the fly" when requested for the first time.